# Intel 12700k - two cores overheating and thermal throttling

Tags: intel-core-i7, cpu-cooler, thermal-paste

I have just replaced an air cooler with an Artic Freezer II 240mm AIO.  Is it doing very well but under synthetic load using multi-core Cinebench R23, two cores are consistently over heating.  On the basis that all P-cores are equal as this test is stress testing the system to 100% CPU.  Is this a Thermal Paste issue?  I can't find a schematic but imagine they are near the edge?  Any thoughts?  90C was the expected outcome from Arctic.

[image]

Comment: If you want to see what your CPU looks like then there is https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/alder_lake#ADL-S_.288P.2B8E.29 the problem is that the cores towards the center cannot flow heat sideways as well as the other cores, which will already be pushing heat there. It's difficult to know the exact thermal situation but it's not surprising that certain cores might run warmer. It's even possible that there is a bubble in whatever material joins the die to the metal heat spreader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the cores are roughly equal in terms of power, but silicon design might mean that those cores are packed away in a slightly worse area. They might be in the centre of the cluster and surrounded by all the other heat generating cores and so run a few degrees hotter than the rest which are on the periphery of the silicon.

The only real options are

- The heatsink is not making good thermal contact. You should unmount it, clean and replace thermal material and refit.
- The fans are not properly ramping up to deal with the thermal load. PWM might not be working - make sure it is connected to power and motherboard fan connectors as required
- The heatsink/AIO unit is underpowered for your system or overclock settings.

Comment: Make sure you use a good quality thermal paste, and that you clean the surface of the CPU and heatsink with isopropyl alcohol and a lint-free cloth. Don't use too much thermal paste, as it can act as an insulator if you're too liberal.

Comment: And examine the thermal paste after demounting the heatsink for any obvious gaps, which would indicate where more paste was needed next time. Unlikely, but something to check for.