# Intel Core-i5 12500H. Is it normal for one P-core to have higher temperatures than the other cores by up to 10 °C?

Tags: cpu, temperature, intel-core-i5, intel

A few days ago I bought a brand new HP Victus 15 laptop with an Intel Core-i5 12500H processor (4 P-cores and 8 E-cores).

During tests for multi-threaded CPU load (I used CinebenchR23) at the same frequencies and voltages on the cores at 100% utilization, one of the cores (namely P-3) has an average temperature of 10 °C higher than the other three P-cores. In Turbo Boost mode, the temperature on this core averages at 97 °C, and reaches a peak of 99 °C (when Thermal Throttling occurs ofc), while the temperatures of the other three cores are within 85-89 °C.

Using the Intel Extreme Tuning Utility I logged the CPU parameters under load (I only used it for logging and didn't do any overclocking) and this situation repeats every time with the same core, and I'm sure that frequencies/voltages of all of the four P-cores are practically the same.

I can't embed images here, but you can view images of the log graph with core temperatures at this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiUzd.png)

I don't know if this is normal or if it's some kind of defect in the laptop's processor or cooling system.

This worries me from the point of view of processor degradation over time on one hotter core, as well as the fact that other cores also throttling due to overheating of one core (so, they do not give the maximum possible performance).

Is this normal or should I return the computer to the seller and ask for a replacement?

Comment: Potential duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/1691060/intel-12700k-two-cores-overheating-and-thermal-throttling

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for pointing out a similar question since I didn't see it. However, I did not see the answer to my question. There is a slight difference, because I have a brand new laptop and I can't replace thermal paste or cooling system etc. But I can return to the sellers and ask for a replacement. Overall, I'm happy with the laptop, except for this issue. So the question is, is this normal or is it still a defect? Can you tell me if it makes sense to mess around with returns and replacements?

Comment: The similarity is in the explanation of "why". You have a number of cores and at least one or a couple of them has to be in a slightly sub-optimal place among the rest of them. Have a look at the comment I left under the question where there is a link to the actual physical layout and you will see the core layouts with big cores sandwiched between other cores. The fact is that *some* thermal disparity is expected and the answer lists only possibilities that might help if you are in a position to apply them.

Comment: I also see a similar difference between cores on my system. Cores 0 & 1 are markedly cooler than cores 4&5 with cores 2&3 and 7&8  (probably physically either side of 4&5) being marginally lower. The temps are 80C (0&1), 86C (2&3), 90C (4&5), 87C (6&7) across my P-core set, with E-cores at 74 and 71 in two groups. Given the physical layout of cores in the CPU  I would not be surprised to see such a heat distribution as the central cores are trying to shed heat into the same areas that other cores are already occupying. My expert hand drawing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRmBo.png

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be normal and is reported in many posts over the internet.
For example see
[13700k P-core 4 & 5 running hotter and faster normal?](https://www.reddit.com/r/intel/comments/10kyzh5/13700k_pcore_4_5_running_hotter_and_faster_normal/).

There have been several explanations for this phenomenon.

Some think that the thread director has some "preferred" cores to whom
it directs more often those jobs that are more demanding on CPU.

There have even been the explanation that some temperature sensors
are placed nearer to the cores than others, so register higher
temperatures.

Whatever the explanation, this is a common observation, so you don't
have to worry.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've read explanations about so-called "preferred cores", but then it must somehow be distinguished from the rest (i.e. have a higher frequency/voltage). However, in this case, I did freq/volt logs for all 4 cores, and the P-3 core doesn't stand out in any way (has the same freq/volt as the other three), but at the same time it has a 10 C higher temperature. I see no physical reason to call this core "preferred". I still don't know if I should ask the seller for a replacement.

Comment: The two explanations are software (Windows) or core firmware (thread controller) or physical layout.